# Appending to file slowdowns the process

Tags: python, performance, file

The process:

1. I read the lookup and create a list `aa`.
2. I traverse through the `glob.glob("C:\\project resource\\dump\\*.html")` and find matching.
3. If a match is found, I create a file if not available, but if available, I just append it to the file.

```
import glob,re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unidecode
lis=[]
aa=open("C:\project resource\lookup.txt","r")
aa=aa.readlines()
aa=[b.split("\t") for b in aa ] 
print "started"
for sa in aa:
    for a in glob.glob("C:\\project resource\\dump\\*.html"):

        if sa[0] =="".join(re.findall("_(\d+).",a)):
            try:
                fi= open(sa[1].strip()+".txt","a")
                html=" ".join(open(a,"r").readlines()[1:])
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
                # kill all script and style elements
                for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
                    script.extract()    # rip it out
                # get text
                text = soup.get_text()
                # break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
                lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
                # break multi-headlines into a line each
                chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
                # drop blank lines
                text = ' '.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
                text=re.sub("\s+"," ",text)

                fi.write(unidecode.unidecode(text)+"\n")
            except:
                print a
            fi.close()
            break
    else:
        print sa,"no match"
```

**lookup.txt sample:**

> ```
> 123\tapple
> 124\tdad
> 125\tdude
> ```

**Sample file names in dump:**

> ```
> 12_123.html
> 12_124.html
> 123234_125.html
> ```

**Time:**

```
File count :1,65,000
Time: 2 days
```

Is there a change which can increase the speed of this process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imports should be on different lines.

```
import glob
import re
```

---

'lis' should be removed, due to it not being used.
If you did use it, it should be renamed, a descriptive name is the best.

---

when opening a file use `with`.

```
with open(...) as aa:
    ...
```

This automatically closes the file, even if there is an unhandled exception. So if for example you keyboard interrupt the program, the file will close.

Also change the variable name `aa` to something better. `file_handler` is better.

---

You overwrite `aa`. This means that you cannot close it.
You should *always* close a file handler.

You could not overwrite `aa` by changing the for statement.

```
for sa in (b.split("\t") for b in aa.readlines()):
```

---

Python's style guide, PEP8, says that all operators should have a space either side.

```
fi = open(sa[1].strip() + ".txt", "a")
```

Currently you use three styles to, one of which is allowed.
The following one line shows two of them. `fi= o` `)+"`

```
fi= open(sa[1].strip()+".txt","a")
```

---

Your try statement is massive. It is also a bare except. Both being very bad.

You should try to keep the `try` as small as possible.
This is so that you don't 'mask' bugs.

```
try:
    file_handler = open(sa[1].strip() + ".txt", "a")
except:
    print "Error on opening " + a
else:
    ...
finally:
    file_handler.close()
```

---

You could remove the print statements. They take a surprising amount of time to print.

---

You should wrap you main in a `if __name__ == '__main__':`

---

## Performance

---

Your massive amount of white-stripping may be the problem.
And you are opening a lot of files.

---

The former you can deal with.

```
text = soup.get_text()
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
text = ' '.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
```

First off this can be simplified.

```
text = ' '.join(
    chunk
    for chunk in (
        phrase.strip()
        for phrase in line.strip().split("  ")
        for line in soup.get_text().splitlines()
    )
    if chunk
)
```

You `strip` every time you `split`. This can't be good.

It seems that you want to replace all blocks of white space with one space.
If this is true then the below function should be simpler and should be faster.

```
def strip_entire(string):
    def inner():
        white_space = False
        for char in string:
            if char in ' \t\n':
                if white_space:
                    continue
                white_space = True
                yield ' '
            else:
                white_space = False
                yield char
    return ''.join(inner())
```

It is \$O(n)\$. And should be faster than yours.

---

If you are likely to open the same file multiple times,
then you could save the output to another file.
Say `a + ".stripped"`

This will have the benefit of being able to reduce the amount of duplicate work.
This is good as then your computer can effortlessly append the file to the other file.

```
with open(sa[1].strip() + ".txt", "a") as file_handler:
    if os.path.exists(a + ".stripped"):
        with open(a + ".stripped", "r") as stripped_handler:
            file_handler.write(stripped_handler.read())
    else:
        # Other method
```

---

If you were to make all these changes you should get

```
import glob
import re
import unidecode
import os.path
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def strip_entire(string):
    def inner():
        white_space = False
        for char in string:
            if char in ' \t\n':
                if white_space:
                    continue
                white_space = True
                yield ' '
            else:
                white_space = False
                yield char
    return ''.join(inner())

def append_file(append_name, html_name):
    with open(append_name, "a") as file_handler:
        if os.path.exists(html_name + ".stripped"):
            with open(html_name + ".stripped", "r") as stripped_handler:
                file_handler.write(stripped_handler.read())
        else:
            with open(html_name, "r") html_handler:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html_handler)
                # If you can't have the first line. No matter what.
                #soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(html_handler.readlines()[1:]))
            for to_remove in soup(("script", "style")):
                to_remove.extract()
            file_handler.write(
                unidecode.unidecode(
                    re.sub("\s+", " ", strip_entire(soup.get_text()))) + "\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("C:\project resource\lookup.txt", "r") as file_handler:
        print("started")
        dump_files = glob.glob("C:\\project resource\\dump\\*.html")
        for split_line in (b.split("\t") for b in file_handler.readlines()):
            for dump_file in dump_files:
                if split_line[0] == "".join(re.findall("_(\d+).", dump_file)):
                    append_file(split_line[1].strip() + ".txt", dump_file)
                    break
```

I don't fully understand what your regex's do.
As I don't fully understand the `re` library.
They seem kinda odd, `re.findall("_(\d+).", dump_file)`,
I thought you only had one number on your files that followed that regex.
And so I decided to leave them as is.

I also removed the try except statement, as I didn't know what you were error handling. Was it your loops, your opens, everything, keyboard interrupts. This is one reason you shouldn't have bare except statements.

If you were doing the `open`s then you should do this:

```
try:
    file_handler = open(...)
except IOError:
    # Raise an error, break, return, whatever.
else:
    # Code in the with
finally:
    file_handler.close()
```

Comment: `with` also closes the file on unhandled exceptions.

Comment: @JoeWallis First time on code review and it is the best experience mate thanks a lot for your time

Comment: @JoeWallis I have certain doubts why should import be on separate lines

Comment: @JoeWallis I had a bare except because there were many error like unicode error ,file unavilable error and so on I just wanted to create files I don't care about the error

Comment: @JoeWallis last but not least I thought calling functions would increase the time and  is there  any performance increase when doing `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: @JoeWallis thanks for your time :D you made many things clear